# pandas to_csv float format arbitrary precision without engineering formating

Tags: python, pandas, precision, export-to-csv

I have a pandas dataframe with arbitrary large and small values (whose magnitude is unknown *a priori*), say:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [0.0000001, 2, 3], 'b' : [4, 5000000, 0.6]})
```

The default display will convert certain numbers to engineering format

```
>>> df
              a          b
0  1.000000e-07        4.0
1  2.000000e+00  5000000.0
2  3.000000e+00        0.6
```

which I don't care. My goal, however, is to write this to a csv file without the engineering format, *while not printing unnecessary 0s either*. The 2nd part of the requirement is to control file size since there are millions of rows.

For example, if I run `df.to_csv(csv_file)` then the file looks like

```
,a,b
0,1e-07,4.0
1,2.0,5000000.0
2,3.0,0.6
```

If I run `df.to_csv(csv_file, float_format="%.7f")` then it looks like (notice all the unnecessary 0s):

```
,a,b
0,0.0000001,4.0000000
1,2.0000000,5000000.0000000
2,3.0000000,0.6000000
```

What I'd like to have in the output file is:

```
,a,b
0,0.0000001,4.0
1,2.0,5000000.0
2,3.0,0.6
```

Is there a simple way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd   
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [0.0000001, 2, 3], 'b' : [4, 5000000, 0.6]})   


def export_formatted(df, csv_path, cols=None):

    # By default, format all columns in df
    if cols==None:
        cols = df.columns

    # Change columns to strings with 0's stripped as desired
    for c in cols:
        df[c] = df[c].map('{:,.15f}'.format).str.rstrip('0')

    # export
    df.to_csv(csv_path)

export_formatted(df, 'stack_overflow_scratch2.csv')
```

provided what I think you want (below):

```
    a               b
0   0.0000001       4
1   2               5000000
2   3               0.6
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, doesn't quite work b/c the `.7f` has to be hard coded but I do not know beforehand how many decimals are the numbers. In particular, if there is a 0.000000001 in my data your function will truncate it to 0, right? That is not the desired result...

Comment: Is there a level of decimal precision that you feel comfortable is definitely conservative enough? Like .15f? Because then hardcoding .15f is still fine and you still only export the digits you need. You could even use the max digits allowed by float if you really wanted.